# Multiple GeoJSON Layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, d3

I have a leaflet map of the US and I would like to toggle between zip codes and county shapes. There seems to be no tutorials on how to achieve this in the documentation or an other forums I have looked at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you have a basemap of the US, and geojson layers for zip codes and county shapes, and you want to toggle (turn on or off) the geojson layers?

Leaflet layer control is designed for this

**Documentation**
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers

**Example**
http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/

Leaflet `L.geoJson()` returns a layer which you can use in the layers control:

```
// parse the geojson (very simplified example here)
var zip = L.geoJson(zipjson, {});
var counties = L.geoJson(countiesjson, {});

// from there, similar to the example: 
var usmap = L.tileLayer(url, {});

// initialize the map
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [39.73, -104.99],
    zoom: 10,
    layers: [usmap]
});

// specify the basemap and overlays to put in the layers control
var baseMaps = {
    "US": usmap,
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "Counties": counties,
    "Zips": zip
};

// initialize up the L.control.layers
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I saw this and I assumed this only toggles between different maps rather than json files with polygon boundaries. As you know, the boundaries for zip code and counties are different so I'm trying to figure out a way to switch between them without having to make a separate map. Am I wrong in assuming this? If so, I can take a further look. Thanks!

Comment: The control toggles between layers. L.geoJson returns a layer you can use in the layer control. I've updated the answer

Comment: Just read your comment again."boundaries for zip code and counties are different". Are you saying the zip code and counties data have a different projection, or do they have a different extent? There are many sources for zip codes and counties that cover the entire US...

Comment: Forgive me, I am unaware of projections vs extent. The overall shape of the zip and counties are the same, it's just that there are different breakdown within it. I hope that's not too confusing.

Comment: that makes sense; should work, as shown above.

Comment: Hrmm right now it doesn't seem to be working. IT's throwing a `Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.` error with leaflet. I passed the maps using your frame work with `var zip = L.geojson ("zipfile.json", {});`, that is correct, right?

Comment: Also prior to this, I was using `queue.js` to load up the map and the json files, does your suggestion compatiable with it?

Comment: many ways to get your geojson data... it will work with the above example, but this is a separate issue, and you should consider asking a new question